# script to color background row column

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to assign a cell color based on a value.  I import the range from a spreadsheet.  I look at each value.  If it is 1 then I want to have the cell color be red, etc. Making the table works fine, but the colors get messed up.  Can't see my error.

```
<? var data = getTheTable(); var lastRow = data.length-1; var      rowsToShow=3; var mcolor='white';?>
<table class="center">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
  </tr>
  <? for (var i = lastRow; i >(lastRow-rowsToShow); i--) { ?>
    <tr>

      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { 
         if (data[i][j]=='1'){mcolor='red';}
        if (data[i][j]=='2'){mcolor='yellow';}
        if (data[i][j]=='3'){mcolor='green';}
        else {mcolor='blue';}
        ?>

        <td> 
        <span style="background-color:<?= mcolor?>;">
        <?= data[i][j] ?></span> </td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use  "else" statements here, (or a switch statement).  Without the else's, each of your ifs is being checked, even if the previous one matched. so even if you match data[i][j] == '1', you still end up with mcolor = 'blue' due to the else on your final if.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

```
  <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { 
        if (data[i][j]=='1'){mcolor='red';}
        else if (data[i][j]=='2'){mcolor='yellow';}
        else if (data[i][j]=='3'){mcolor='green';}
        else { mcolor='blue'; }

      ...
```

Often if you find yourself using a bunch of if/else statements in a row, a Switch/Case is a cleaner option:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

```
switch(data[i][j]){
    case '1':
        mcolor='red';
        break;
    case '2':
       mcolor='yellow';
       break;
    case '3':
        mcolor='green';
        break;
    default:
        mcolor='blue';
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just figured it out.  I program in too many languages. Some don't  need the "else".... you guys are great!!